# VBA Moving images to new worksheets same location

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code below for transposing information to new sheets from a master sheet. The first three columns are a template (a school report card) and it goes to every new sheet. The next columns (student grades) go individually to different sheets, always appearing in column D alongside the template.

#### Here's the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

#### Here's the code:

```
`Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()
    Dim studsSht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim stud As Variant

    Set studsSht = Worksheets("Input")
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In studsSht.Range("D7:Q7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            .Item(cell.Value) = .Item(cell.Value) & cell.EntireColumn.Address(False, False) & ","
        Next
        For Each stud In .keys 
            Intersect(studsSht.UsedRange, studsSht.Range(Left(.Item(stud), Len(.Item(stud)) - 1))).Copy Destination:=GetSheet(CStr(stud)).Range("D1") 
        Next
    End With

    studsSht.Activate
End Sub

Function GetSheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set GetSheet = Worksheets(shtName)
If GetSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set GetSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    GetSheet.Name = shtName
    Sheets("Input").Range("A1:C63").Copy
    GetSheet.Range("A1:D63").PasteSpecial xlAll
End If
End Function`
```

My issue is that the template also contains logos (I have removed them from the screenshot for obvious reasons), but I can't get them to go to the new sheets.

I've tried placing the logos on a hidden sheet where I want them to appear in the new sheets and replacing `Sheets.Add` with `HiddenSheet.Copy` but it bugs out. I think I'm trying to make the code transpose two templates then, one on top of the other. That would be fine if someone could make it work.

I also tried using TopLeft Centre, but the logos come up offset from where they were. I would prefer the template approach.

Any help for a relative newb?

Comment: Why do you need a hidden sheet if the logos are present in the "input" sheet? You could then try `Sheets("Input").Copy after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`?

Comment: It has an issue with the line `Intersect(studsSht.UsedRange, studsSht.Range(Left(.Item(stud), Len(.Item(stud)) - 1))).Copy Destination:=GetSheet(CStr(stud)).Range("D1")` The way that the sheets are added is by finding the students names and opening sheets in those names, copying the template onto the new sheets (it's here that the logos are not part of the copy for some reason), and then copying the student data column into column D. If I change it to `HiddenSheet.Copy` or `Sheets("Input").copy` then it does not want to paste the student data on top.

Comment: And even if I arrange the logos to make sure they are within this range `Sheets("Input").Range("A1:C63").Copy
    GetSheet.Range("A1:D63").PasteSpecial xlAll` they don't transfer (I suppose that's because I'm copying data from the sheet, and not the sheet itself). But, as I stated above, If I copy the sheet itself then the VBA code doesn't work because the input sheet includes data that the code is trying to remove. One part is trying to get rid of data, the other is trying to copy it in.

Comment: I think what I need is an extra couple of lines of code which deal specifically with images. So the code says add sheets, copy the template, copy student data, AND transpose logos from hidden sheet/input sheet to all new sheets in same location. But I'm a bit stuck.